# How to see log on a AWS Worker in PHP?

Tags: php, logging, amazon-sqs, worker

I'm having some troubles trying to fix a project running on an AWS instance as a Worker.

When I'm posting a json on local machine, everything works just fine.
When deploying, I can insert messages in my SQS and they are called by my Worker deamon.
However, I can see that nothing happens. I tried to add some logs, but I can't even see httpd logs.

Is that normal? Where can I find what's happening when a message is received by the deamon and when it's sent to my Worker?

Thanks for your time, will respond any question.

**EDIT**

On my instance, in the /var/log/aws-sqsd/default.log log file, I can see an error I do not understand:

```
socket-err: a65396c5-6227-49ff-8f7b-a0f7d40d8e01 (390) Errno::ECONNRESET - 104.706
```

Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to rebuild your environment.